# Get only Mac address from IP (bash)

Tags: bash, awk, grep, arp

I want to grep the MAC address in `arp -n`.

I tried this: `$ arp | grep 192.168.15.1 | awk '{print $3}'`

But i end up like this:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

*I censored the macs*

I want only a single MAC address, how can i get it ?

Comment: In your original solution if you use `grep -m1` then you will get the desired result, although using `grep` and `awk` together is redundant as `awk` is "almost" capable of doing everything which `grep` can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arp | awk '/192.168.15.1/{print $3;exit}'
```

By using this command, you will get only 1 mac.

If you want to adopt an input of bash script to be the addr, use the command below,

```
arp -n $1 | awk -v a=$1 '$0 ~ a{print $3;exit}'
```

use `-v a=$1` to assign `$1` of bash to the variable `a` in `awk`

Comment: `arp -n 192.168.15.1 | awk '/192.168.15.1/{print $3;exit}'`
This is working for me :)

I'll write a Bash Script like this: `
arp -n $1 | awk '/'$1'/{print $3;exit}'`

Comment: arp is deprecated, using it will cause your scripts to fail at some time unless you don't upgrade your systems, making them highly vulnerable

Comment: @MrFlyingToasterman, see my modified answer if you want to use it in bash

Answer (score 2):

```
ip -brief link show |grep -v LOOPBACK|awk '{print $3;}'
```

Comment: I need a remote MAC not my own.

Comment: Just change link to neighbor